# Opening a .tif image using matplotlib Python

Tags: python-2.7, image-processing, matplotlib

I am pretty new to python and I am trying to load a .tif image into the following code in order to later mark it with dots at various x and y coordinates.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
image = mpimg.imread("mothTest.tif")
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

I've used the following image: [image]

and it produces the following errors:

```
  File "<ipython-input-1-69a4ce2424d3>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('Z:/04PROJECTS Internal/GEMultiplexerProject/Method/StatisticalMethods/Cell Arangement APP/Python App/Centroid_LUT.py', wdir='Z:/04PROJECTS Internal/GEMultiplexerProject/Method/StatisticalMethods/Cell Arangement APP/Python App')

  File "C:\Users\Michaela\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\Michaela\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 87, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

  File "Z:/04PROJECTS Internal/GEMultiplexerProject/Method/StatisticalMethods/Cell Arangement APP/Python App/Centroid_LUT.py", line 29, in <module>
    image = mpimg.imread("mothTest.tif")

  File "C:\Users\Michaela\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 1278, in imread
    im = pilread(fname)

  File "C:\Users\Michaela\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 1256, in pilread
    with Image.open(fname) as image:

  File "C:\Users\Michaela\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 512, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)

AttributeError: __exit__
```

Does anyone happen to know how to work around this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Using python 2.7, matplotlib 2.0.2, PIL 1.1.7, Pillow 3.0 the above code runs without problem and loads the tif image.

Comment: I am having some difficulty installing the Pillow package. When I go to install it via .exe Pillow-3.0.0-py2.7.egg-info gets installed into my site packages instead of the package itself. I have also tried to download it right from git into my site-packages, but when i go to check if it has been imported properly (via import Pillow) I get an error stating that the package is not in the site-packages folder

Comment: The recommended way to install pillow is [`pip install Pillow`](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/installation.html). Using anaconda you can also use its package manager directly, although I would think that anaconda has pillow installed by default.

Comment: Thank you! I realized I was having issues because I had PIL installed instead of Pillow. Everything is working now!

Comment: You may then answer your own question and accept that answer in 2 days time, such that this question will not stay unsolved forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.2.x/installation.html) for Pillow, PIL and Pillow cannot coexist in the same environment. I had previously installed PIL, so after I uninstalled PIL and installed Pillow 3.0 from [this link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/3.0.0), everything worked smoothly with the code posted above.